# passing along query string when mapping URLs with varnish

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

For a web service I'm working on, we're using varnish to map "user friendly" URLs to the longer URL where the page is actually located. So for example:

real URL:          https://example.com/stuff/things/page.php

user-friendly URL: https://example.com/page

So the way we're achieving this in vcl is as follows:

```
if (req.url ~ "page") {
    set req.url = stuff/things/page.php
}
```

But now I'm running into a problem in which the query string is getting wiped out in the process. So something to the effect of https://example.com/page?username=Ataraxia just gets mapped to https://example.com/stuff/things/page.php, but I need the query string to pass through to the mapped URL. Does anyone know how I could achieve this through varnish? I'm thinking I'll need to extract the query string via a regex operation and append it to the mapped URL, but I'm new to vcl and am unsure if this is possible, or if there's a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I did not test it but this might do the job:

```
if (req.url ~ "page") {
    set req.url = "/stuff/things/page.php" + regsub(req.url, "[^?]*", "");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I'm still working on testing this (I'm running into some other issues) but I'll be sure to accept your answer once I verify it working :)

Answer (score 1):

This is what i do, and works like a charm, i know this is 2 years later response, but might help someone.

```
if (req.url ~ "page") {
   set req.url = regsub(req.url, "page", "stuff/things/page.php\1");
}
```